# Send Stack Trace Information On A queryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am calling an actionResult from my global.ascx file like so...

```
 Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?message={1}", action, exception.Message));
```

What I would like to do is have the whole exception object available in the action result method so I can get and display the stack trace info on my page....Is it possible to pass along the whole exception object? What is the best way to handle this? Or is there a work around to get the proper Stack Trace info? Currently its a property that is populated correctly on the exception object.

Comment: Can you put it in your tempdata?  Usually I just log the exception and use the logs to debug

Comment: @Phil, `TempData` and redirect to handle exceptions? 302 Status code instead of 500? Doesn't feel very RESTful or SEO friendly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you redirect you can't send complex objects. I mean you could use `Session` and `TempData` (which uses Session behind the scenes) but it's ugly and something I would recommend against.

If you want complex objects don't redirect. Set proper status code and transfer which is much more RESTful and SEO friendly:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();
    Context.ClearError();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http500";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

where ErrorController looks like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Http500(Exception exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        // TODO: do something with the exception like logging it 
        // and render some view explaining the annoyed user 
        // that something very wrong happened to your application 
        // which wasn't your fault of course or something
    }
}
```

If you redirect you can't send complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to do this is to use the TempData collection.

```
TempData["myException"] = exception;
```

It acts as a store of data for the next request only (for the current client of course). However, I believe it is only accessible from within a Controller, so you might have to reorganise your code such that your error handling occurs within a controller (I have some sample code that I don't have access to right now, but will put up shortly that will explain this better).

Comment: `TempData` and redirect to handle exceptions? 302 Status code instead of 500? Doesn't feel very RESTful or SEO friendly.

Comment: If its an internal application (which it is in my case), SEO is irrelevant. RESTful is an ideal objective. I will give your technique a go however!

Comment: is *intranet application* synonym for *crap application*? I mean that fact that it's an intranet application doesn't mean that we shouldn't respect web standards, does it? After all, it's a web application, isn't it? So respecting web standards and the HTTP specification seems like a crucial part for me in every web application. Why making a distinction between intranet and internet?